# What are graphical model 'normals'?

Tags: graphics, 3d, 2d

I understand that 'position' is where the model is currently located in space.  'Vertices' determine the shape of the model.  What are the 'normals' of a model?

Comment: By the conventional mathematical definition, a *normal* is a (unit) vector perpendicular to a surface (at a particular point). However in the context of computer graphics, they may not be exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

### Normals as used in 3D

Normals are vectors that are used to define properties for vertices, and polygons.

The word "Normals" come from the original usage, Normals were the normalised vectors pointing out from a polygon (face) defining the direction the face is pointing.

A normalized vector is a vector that has a length of 1 unit. Though for the general usage these vectors can be any length if desired.

Precomputed normals in the early days of CG increased performance and were used to calculate various shading effects and for quick backface culls (test if a face is facing towards the camera or away).

As hardware performance increased people found uses for normals other than just lighting, and culling. Things like occlusion lighting, displacement effects, translucency, any number of surface detail effects, and what ever your imagination could find a use for.

Generally normals are transformed along with the vertices that define the faces, but these days normals are calculated on the fly.

As software rendering pipelines increased in performance and were integrated with hardware the word normals stuck when describing any of the additional vectors used to describe the mesh some property of a mesh.

#### Quick visual representation.

[image]

A mesh is constructed from verts (3D points x,y,z) and faces are constructed by connecting 3 verts to make triangles. Faces can have a face normal that is the normalised cross product of two of the faces edges (a line connecting 2 verts). Vert normals represent the average surface direction at that point and are used to create smooth shaded surfaces. They are computed by normalizing the summed face normals connected to that vert.

#### Normal maps.

There are also normal maps that are textures containing a normal for each pixel (the RGB become XYZ). When added to the face or surface normals they can create  additional per fragment effects.